# Why is my include loading inside my <body>

Tags: php, include

I have an include for my `DB` and also for the content. i was wondering why my `db.php` is loading inside my body tag

```
<?php 

    include('includes/db.php');

    include('html/basic_page_content.html');

?>
```

the db.php only contains `mysql_connect()` that connects to my database and a `mysql_select_db()`.

my basic_page_content.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Basic Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h3> simple page </h3>

    </body>
</html>
```

That It should be loading above the head part

Comment: Within the HTML, where are you including the files?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm not sure what you mean by "loading inside" your `body` tag - is there visible output from `includes/db.php`, like some error text? - but if I had to guess, it isn't really: your browser is moving the file's output into `body` because text content doesn't go anywhere else.

Modern browsers do an astonishing amount of jiggery to make webpages display "right," and this very often means that the exact opposite occurs.

I'm guessing your real problem is that there's error text or other DB output showing up that you don't want displayed. Try putting an @ before your commands to suppress error text - or maybe add some error checking to your database handling code. ;)